# How to put together 2 new additional columns made using a case statement together in SQL

Tags: sql, case-statement

```
SELECT 
    ScheduledStartDate, ActualStartDate, ScheduledEndDate, ActualEndDate,
    CASE 
       (WHEN ActualStartDate > ScheduledStartDate THEN 'started late'
        WHEN ActualStartDate < ScheduledStartDate THEN 'started early'
        WHEN ScheduledStartDate = ActualStartDate then 'started on time'
    END AS startDescription )
    ELSE
    CASE 
      (WHEN ActualEndDate < ScheduledEndDate THEN 'finished late'
       WHEN ActualEndDate > ScheduledEndDate THEN 'finished early'
       WHEN ActualEndDate = ScheduledEndDate THEN 'finished on time'
    END AS endDescription )
FROM
    [Production].[WorkOrderRouting];
```

I have made 4 columns and want to add 2 new columns made with 'case' statement together.

Comment: Sample data and desired result would help to understand what you want. Maybe you just want to replace `ELSE` wit `,` and remove the parenthesis?

Comment: What do you mean by `Add columns`? Do you mean you need to see a result like `started late, finished on time` together

Comment: @Utsav the new columns made should show endDescription, and startDescription as per the case condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each `CASE` expression a separate column:

```
SELECT
    ScheduledStartDate,
    ActualStartDate,
    ScheduledEndDate,
    ActualEndDate,
    CASE WHEN ActualStartDate > ScheduledStartDate THEN 'started late'
         WHEN ActualStartDate < ScheduledStartDate THEN 'started early'
         WHEN ActualStartDate = ScheduledStartDate THEN 'started on time' END AS startDescription,
    CASE WHEN ActualEndDate < ScheduledEndDate THEN 'finished late'
         WHEN ActualEndDate > ScheduledEndDate THEN 'finished early'
         WHEN ActualEndDate = ScheduledEndDate THEN 'finished on time' END AS endDescription
FROM [Production].[WorkOrderRouting];
```